# How to Merge One File From Branch to Master Git

Tags: git

I am still getting a feel for Git. This might be a pretty basic question.

I have two branches ("master" and "switch_to_fulfill_by_item"). I completed the changes I needed to a particular file in "switch_to_fulfill_by_item" and I would like to merge these changes to the master branch. But my co-workers has in the meantime made dozens of changes.

Here is the basic question: *how do I merge just this one file without overwriting all of my co-workers work?*

Thanks,

- Jesse

Comment: Git is not a file based version control system.  In Git, a snapshot of _every_ file in the repository is made each time you version (commit).  So ideally all you need to do is merge your branch to `master`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is the essence of git. When you try to merge your branch `switch_to_fulfill_by_item` into the `master` branch, if your colleague has been working on the similar area of the file you edited, a few **not-to-be-worried** about *merge conflicts* can arise. If conflicts arise, just sit with your colleague & figure out what changes you actually need.
You can start merge your changes in `switch_to_fulfill_by_item` to `master` by:

```
git checkout master
git merge switch_to_fulfill_by_item
```

If no conflicts arise (which has higher probability of happening), you are done now. Your changes will now be available in `master`. 
*Side-Note: You should consider creating a [Pull Request](https://help.github.com/articles/about-pull-requests/) for your changes before merging to `master`.*

Comment: The question specifically asked to merge a single file and not all the changes from the other branch.  This doesn't answer the original post.

Answer (score 2):

You must `commit` the changes in your development branch, then switch to master, `git fetch`, `git rebase` so you download all the changes that your team has done in to your local version and now you're ready to `merge` the branches.  If there were any conflicts, you can choose which version you keep, IntelliJ's integrated interface for Git is pretty good and intuitive with conflict solving.